# How to resample a grouped dataframe with zero order hold?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-resample, pandas-timeindex

I have a dataframe with a bunch of different measurements (each have a unique ID in a `measurements` column), and measurement samples taken each 10ms.

Now I want to downsample all my data in order to "fake" a different sampling time, e.g. 40ms, for all measurements.

I implemented the resampling as shown below, but now I'm stuck: I do not want to perform an aggregation like `.mean()` on the resampler object, as this would process information from all samples in the respective 40ms bin.

```
df.set_index('timedelta', inplace=True)
df.index = pd.to_timedelta(df.index, unit='S')
df= df_resampled.groupby('measurement').resample('40ms')
```

Instead, I want to take only the first value within the resampled 40ms bin and hold it - basically, just pick the latest given value each 40ms.

Is there an elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66754074/revisions) to the question [How to resample a grouped dataframe with zero order hold?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66754074/how-to-resample-a-grouped-dataframe-with-zero-order-hold) by the OP [Rejaho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15455689/rejaho) under CC BY-SA 4.0.

> Do:
>
> ```
> df_resampled.groupby('measurement').resample('40ms').first()
> ```
>
> See pandas' `.first`
> [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.1/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.first.html#pandas.core.resample.Resampler.first).